# Cannot get .NET assembly name via PowerShell

Tags: .net, powershell, system.reflection

I'm trying to debug a DLL loading issue with my application, and part of my process involves verifying the runtime dependencies for my assemblies.  I wanted to check the bitness of my DLLs as well, just to make sure nothing is mismatched.

Anyhow, I am trying to use PowerShell to do this, but it's never able to find the DLL that I have specified.  As a sanity check, I decided to try a .NET 4 assembly, and it still fails.

Please see the following image -- what am I doing wrong here?

[image]

I've seen suggestions elsewhere, like running PowerShell as admin and also using `Set-ExecutionPolicy unrestricted`.  I've done those, without any success.

Comment: Don't use relative paths.

Answer (score 1):

Before passing *relative paths* to .NET methods, execute the following, to ensure that .NET uses the same working directory as PowerShell (which is *not* the case by default, unfortunately):

```
[Environment]::CurrentDirectory = $PWD
```

Alternatively, prefix relative paths with `$PWD` to convert them to absolute ones; in your example:

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::GetAssemblyName("$PWD\System.Net.dll")
```

Comment: As a note, some things don't like when dynamic variables are passed to them (modules in particular, not sure about .net static methods).  I'd suggest `$Path = "$PWD\System.Net.dll"; [type]::method($Path)`

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1: The interpolating string is expanded _before_ the .NET method ever sees it, so I don't think there's a problem here.